# Вычислить шанс для индекса массива

Tags: php, javascript, java, c++, алгоритм

Есть массив с индексами от 1 до 9. Каждый индекс это шанс умноженный на 10 (то есть индекс 1 это 10% шанс, 2 это 20% и до 9 = 90%), что будет выбран именно этот индекс, задача определить индекс.

Пришел к такому решению: Создать массив в котором количество значений будет равно номеру индекса с номером индекса.
Пример:

```
arr[1] = [1]
arr[2] = [2]
arr[3] = [2]
arr[4] = [3]
arr[5] = [3]
arr[6] = [3]
arr[7] = [4]
arr[8] = [4]
arr[9] = [4]
arr[10] = [4]
...
arr[..] = [7] //не считал какой именно получается номер индекса
arr[..] = [7]
arr[..] = [7]
arr[..] = [7]
arr[..] = [7]
arr[..] = [7]
...
```

Далее cделать suffle массива (хоть по сути и не обязательно).

Далее сделать $rand = rand(1,count(arr))

И результат будет arr[$rand] - значение и будет индекс массива от 1 до 9...

Вопрос: правильно ли я все понял, если да, то какие есть альтернативы проще...

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ДЛЯ НЕ ПОНИМАЮЩИХ ЗАДАЧУ:**

Перед вами 9-ть дверей, у каждой двери есть номер 1, 2, 3, 4...9. Шанс что вы зайдете в дверь с номером 1 = 10%, шанс что зайдете в дверь с номером 2 = 20%, шанс что зайдете в дверь с номер 7 = 70% и так далее до двери с номер 9 у которой шанс 90% что вы туда зайдете. В какую дверь войдете вы?

**Как вариант №2**

```
// если не из 45, а из 10
$randNum = rand(1, 90)
if($randNum = 1 or $randNum = 2) return 1  // 2%
elseif($randNum >= 3 and $randNum <= 6) return 2 // 4%
elseif($randNum >= 7 and $randNum <= 12) return 3 // 6%
elseif($randNum >= 13 and $randNum <= 20) return 4 // 8%
elseif($randNum >= 21 and $randNum <= 30) return 5 // 10%
elseif($randNum >= 31 and $randNum <= 42) return 6 // 12%
elseif($randNum >= 43 and $randNum <= 56) return 7 // 14%
elseif($randNum >= 57 and $randNum <= 72) return 8 // 16%
elseif($randNum >= 73 and $randNum <= 90) return 9 // 18%
//90%
```

На это все! разобрался...

Comment: Вслушайтесь в эти слова: "индекс 1 это 10% шанс, ... 9 = 90%". Значит 1 и 9 вместе 100%. А остальные? У Вас сколько всего процентов-то?

Comment: Мне кажется задача чисто математическая и чтобы найти "шанс для индекса массива" нужно решить эту задачу: `В мешке находится  1 шар с цифрой 1, 2 шара с цифрой 2, 3 шара с цифрой 3 .... 9 шаров с цифрой 9. Какова вероятность вытащить шар с каждой цифрой?`

Comment: @MasterAlex если так, то `n/45`

Comment: А как же условие задачи (никто не читает)? Вычислить индекс массива от 1 до 9, если у каждого индекса есть свой шанс от 10% до 90%

Comment: @user3737786 - Пока у Вас будет получаться 450%, Вы задачу не решите.

Comment: @Igor с вами все ясно =)

Comment: @user3737786 - "задача определить индекс" - какой индекс?

Comment: @user3737786, я согласен с Igor`ом. У вас действительно не так что-то с процентами либо вы неправильно донесли до нас суть задания. Постарайтесь понятней изложить суть задачи, что бы ее могли решить..

Comment: @Igor Ответ есть и условии вопроса и на 2 комментария выше

Comment: 1) Почему нет метки типа "Алгоритм", но есть куча языковых меток, которые нафиг не нужны (`PHP` ещё ладно)? 2) 450%? Это ж как так? Бинарно - может быть, унарно - невозможно, процент не может быть больше 100.

Comment: Добавил дополнение к вопросу.

Comment: Дополнение ничего не пояснило. Проценты **складываются**, а значит выходит чушь. Т. е. шанс войти в двери 8 и 9 = 170% => в остальные двери никто не войдёт с точностью больше 100%, т. е. вообще никогда. А это чушь.

Comment: @Other, да в том то и дело, что совокупный шанс события должен быть равен 100%, если совокупный шанс события 450%, то реальные шансы уменьшаются в 4.5, иначе в 9 из 10 вариантов должен быть индекс 9 при этом в 8 из 10 вариантов должен быть индекс 8, далее продолжать бессмысленно, уже перебор.

Comment: @MasterAlex, что-то вспомнилось о Стране Чудес Кэрролла :)

Comment: @MasterAlex Вот по этому я и предлагаю шанс не из 10 а из 45

Comment: и откровенно спросил, есть или альтернативы проще

Comment: @MasterAlex просто 100% шанс не должен быть, так как если 100%-ный шанс, то будет выбираться индекс постоянно, то есть если не из 45, а из 10, то шанс будет такой для индекса 1 = 2%, для индекса 2 = 4%, для индекса 3 = 6% ... для индекса 9 = 18%

Comment: А зачем у вас проверки `($randNum >=`? Если уж попали в эту ветку, то понятно, что оно больше или равно нижней границы, иначе отработалось бы более ранней веткой...

Comment: @user373778, в итоге ваше второе решение мало чем отличается от первого, только количество шариков умножается на 2, да и процент в комментарии написан с ошибкой, получается сумма всех вероятностей - 90%, а не 100, например, для 9 будет 20 %, а не 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем просто, если можно сложно :)

Вот, на C/C++:

```
int idx = int((sqrt(20.0*(rand()%450)+25)-5)/10.0 + 1);
```

Вот распределение 10000 полученных таким методом чисел:

```
1    214
2    439
3    673
4    903
5   1084
6   1330
7   1649
8   1782
9   1926
```

Answer (score 0):

А если вероятность считать не нужно, а нужно просто вытащить из мешка шарик с номером, то на `javascript` можно придумать такое решение на скорую руку (на решение месяца не претендую, думаю есть более гибкие варианты):

```js
var arr = [];
var k = 0;
var b = 10;

// заполняем мешок шариками
for (var i = 1; i < b; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    arr[k] = i;
    k++;
  }
}

// Перемешиваем
function sRand() {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
}
arr.sort(sRand);

// Вытаскиваем первый шарик
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Вы написали код также, по сути, как предложил я.

Comment: С логической точки зрения также, другой логики тут быть и не может, а с технологической точки зрения по-другому, вы сразу жарите мясо, а я сначала немного мариную, а потом прижариваю :)